# How to use linux shell variable in file paths in java

Tags: java

I have set String `location` in java file, for Linux Environment.

```
String location = "/APPL_TOP2/IMDD/apps/apps_st/appl/xxfin/12.0.0/bin/xe.csv";
```

When I'm using above location it does generate a csv file.

Now my client is asking if it's it possible to give relative path.

I entered a relative linux shell path like below.

```
String location = "$XXFIN_TOP\\12.0.0\\bin\\xe.csv";
```

But it doesn't translate to an absolute file path.

How can I translate linux shell paths to usuable paths in my java application?

Comment: What is "$XXFIN_TOP"?  And post the actual error pls.

Comment: please if u know the answer Give otherwise ..

Comment: From the information you've given, the answer is: "$XXFIN_TOP\12.0.0\bin\xe.csv" doesn't exist.  Without more information it's impossible to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `System.getenv("XXFIN_TOP");`

Your path would become:

```
 String location = System.getenv("XXFIN_TOP")+"\\12.0.0\\bin\\xe.csv";
```

Comment: I don't see it in his code? I only see single backslash.

Comment: Ah right, I edited the question and I saw heh. Thanks for pointing out @Tom , now I also as a result discovered OP's actual question :-)

Comment: Ah, so $XXFIN_TOP is an environment var.  It would have been so much easier if OP just told us that.

Comment: If it works in shell it works in java right? right? no explanation needed. I glanced over it at first too until I had a 'Waaaiiit a minute" moment and recognized it as a shell variable that i'm used to under linux.

Comment: HI It is not creating file Not working please share anyone

Comment: @Babu Please update your question with details on where the $XXFIN_TOP is set. Is it set in shell? what do you get if you do `echo $XXFIN_TOP` shell? Have you tried `export XXFIN_TOP="/APPL_TOP2/IMDD/apps/apps_st/appl/xxfin"` ?

Comment: String location = System.getenv("XXFIN_TOP")+"\\12.0.0\\bin\\xe.csv";  this is working fine and  creating file. bt I need to place my file in bin folder.       My location like this "/APPL_TOP2/IMDD/apps/apps_st/appl/xxfin/12.0.0/bin/xe.csv";